# Creating a For Loop using a named list

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I'm trying to create a for loop for the code below.

The list of account as below:

[[image]]

```
For Each Account In Accounts

    With Range("A1", "K" & lngLastRow)
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Account
        .Copy OKSheet.Range("A1")
        .AutoFilter
    End With
        Sheets("Summary").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0).Select

Next Accounts
```

Comment: And what isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

So without further info lets have a look at what could be changed with respect to what you have posted:

1) I can't see your variable declarations so i don't know how, and whether, you declared your variables, nor if you have `Option Explicit` at the top. So you could be getting errors such as `Type mismatch` or `Application-defined or Object-defined error`. We don't know as you don't state.

2)  `With Range("A1", "K" & lngLastRow)` We don't know how you have calculated lngLastRow so this might terminate prematurely due to empty cells in a column.
It also implicitly references the `Activesheet` as isn't fully qualified as a range.

3) `For Each Account In Accounts` We don't know the variables types here so this might cause a type mismatch error, for example. I am unsure if `Accounts`, is meant to be a Range or a Named Range (or something else, possibly an Array)?

4)   `.Copy OKSheet.Range("A1")` Inside a loop, without incrementing in some way, you will overwrite cell `A1` with the contents of the filter at the current loop iteration. Meaning, you will end up with whatever the last filter criteria was in cell `A1` in the destination sheet.

5)  1st `.AutoFilter` You clear the filter at the end of each loop so this may be redundant, depends on whether range is already filtered at start of loop.

6) The following three lines, within the loop, i think are redundant, as they don't actually do anything  (except potentially produce an error) since your loop is over a defined range (Definitely a collection object or Array, we hope) and you will be returning to the next element.

```
Sheets("Summary").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0).Select
```

And even if it were not looping to a specified range, you don't functionally achieve anything with these steps that couldn't be done with a single cell selection outside of the loop.

The following

```
Sheets("Summary").Select
```

As one should avoid [.Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), where possible, *could* become

```
Sheets("Summary").Activate
```

if there is not something in cell `A2`, or beyond, then the following line has taken us to the land of `Application defined or object defined error` by trying to jump off the end of the spreadsheet.

```
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0).Select
```

`Selection.End(xlDown)` has taken us to the last row in the sheet and then there is an attempt to offset a further two rows.

You could use (and i suspect outside of the loop)

```
Sheets("Summary").Cells(Sheets("Summary").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Activate
```

With that in mind

**With `Accounts` as a Range object code might look like:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TEST()

    Dim Accounts As Range  'Variable declarations
    Dim Account As Range

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim OKSheet As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'Variable assignments
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set OKSheet = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim nextOKRow As Long

    lngLastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row by coming from the bottom of the sheet and finding last used cell in column

    Set Accounts = wsSource.Range("A1:A" & lngLastRow) 'define Accounts

    For Each Account In Accounts

        nextOKRow = OKSheet.Cells(OKSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'increment where you paste

        If nextOKRow > 1 Then nextOKRow = nextOKRow + 1

        With wsSource.Range("A1:K" & lngLastRow) 'fully qualify range   'could also have as  With wsSource.Range("A1", "K" & lngLastRow)
            .AutoFilter 'redundant?
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Account
            .Copy OKSheet.Range("A" & nextOKRow) 'here you were just pasting over the same cell each time
            .AutoFilter
        End With

        '  Sheets("Summary").Range("A1").Activate
        'Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0).Select ' off the sheet.   'not actually doing anything as you revisit the next Account range

    Next Account

     ''Potentially uncomment the following two lines
    'Sheets("Summary").Activate
    'Sheets("Summary").Cells(Sheets("Summary").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Activate


End Sub
```

**With `Accounts` as a Named Range:**

```
Public Sub TEST2()

    Dim Account As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim OKSheet As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set OKSheet = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim nextOKRow As Long

    lngLastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    wsSource.Range("A1:A" & lngLastRow).Name = "Accounts"

    For Each Account In wb.Names("Accounts").RefersToRange

        nextOKRow = OKSheet.Cells(OKSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        If nextOKRow > 1 Then nextOKRow = nextOKRow + 1

        With wsSource.Range("A1:K" & lngLastRow)
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Account
            .Copy OKSheet.Range("A" & nextOKRow)
            .AutoFilter
        End With

    Next Account

End Sub
```

**With `Accounts` as an Array:**

```
Public Sub TEST3()

    Dim Accounts()  'Variable declarations
    Dim Account As Variant

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim OKSheet As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set OKSheet = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim nextOKRow As Long

    lngLastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Accounts = wsSource.Range("A1:A" & lngLastRow).Value

    For Each Account In Accounts

        nextOKRow = OKSheet.Cells(OKSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        If nextOKRow > 1 Then nextOKRow = nextOKRow + 1

        With wsSource.Range("A1:K" & lngLastRow)
             .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Account
            .Copy OKSheet.Range("A" & nextOKRow)
        End With

    Next Account

End Sub
```